# Google Form with an alert

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created a registration form with Google Forms. Now I would like to have an alert displayed before the submitter starts filling out data.

This is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  FormApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addToUi();
}
function showAlert() {
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
     'Lorem ipsum',
     'dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

The triggers were set up. 
The script works fine but only while a form is in in the editing mode, not in a view mode. Actually I'm the only one who can see the message box. It's not what I meant to ;-). How to show this alert to everyone who is going to fill out my form?

Answer (score 1):

The Forms Service of Google Apps Scripts doesn't have methods for the respondent view. Actually, there isn't a Google Apps Script service or Google API to be used to extend the respondent view of Google Forms.

One alternative is to embed the Google Form in a web page or application that allow the use of alerts, i.e. Google Sites.

**References**

- [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

Comment: Does it mean that there is no way to show any alert or message box in respondent view? Do I have to use only text in the form itself if I want to communicate something to the submitter?

Comment: There are many ways to show an alert. Your question is about using certain code. Anyway, I added to my answer a hint about one alternative.

Comment: As I know, Google Sites do not have preset alerts